# Problems using "camera_windows" package in flutter running on windows. (Error in the description)

Tags: flutter, windows, camera, record, pub.dev

I have an app in flutter which is going to start running on Windows. The objective is to be able to record videos with a Logitech webcam and using the "camera_windows" package. When trying to use the example left at https://pub.dev/packages/camera_windows/example , I receive the error [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(camera_error, The data specified for this media type are not valid, consistent, or compatible with this object., null, null), just as I try to start recording, when (await CameraPlatform.instance.startVideoRecording(_cameraId);) is executed. How can I solve that? Or is there another package that can help me?

As I said before, I have tried to literally use the example left by the package developers at https://pub.dev/packages/camera_windows/example but I receive the error
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(camera_error, The data specified for this media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object., null, null), when " await CameraPlatform.instance.startVideoRecording(_cameraId); " is executed